# Why "create!" instead of create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to learn RSpec following their doc at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails. However, their sample uses a function create! that RubyMine doesn't recognize and I didn't know it.

How it works? Is it implemented in the ActiveRecord base class?

Here is the sample I'm talking about:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  it "orders by last name" do
    lindeman = User.create!(first_name: "Andy", last_name: "Lindeman")
    chelimsky = User.create!(first_name: "David", last_name: "Chelimsky")

    expect(User.ordered_by_last_name).to eq([chelimsky, lindeman])
  end
end
```

Comment: It's in the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an ActiveRecord method.

`create` will return either `true` or `false`.
`create!` will raise an Exception if the operation fails.

Comment: That's not correct.  `User.create` will return a User instance which may be presisted or may not, if the validation failed, bu it always returns a User instance.  `User.create!` will return a User instance or will raise an exception.